# Drag-and-Drop Word Rearrangement Software

Tags: windows, drag-drop

I'm looking for something (not web-based) that will allow me to have several screens, each consisting of several movable objects (ideally containing text), that a user can rearrange to make a valid sentence before proceeding to the next screen. Then, the user can finally save the state of their screens.

For example, you *could* do this in something like PowerPoint: On each slide, create a number of text boxes, then get the user to move them around appropriately and save the presentation under their name. However, PowerPoint isn't ideal, as it has slightly non-intuitive behaviour when objects overlap and it's designed with the presumption that you want to edit the text (not an unreasonable assumption while editing!)... However, that gives you an example of what's needed.

Any better ideas?

(I realise this would be relatively easy to put together in HTML+JavaScript, but I don't have the resources necessary to run a local server to save responses.)

Comment: ...It being free is also a (loose) requirement

Comment: Does the output format matter? (e.g., plain text, images, PDF, …)

Comment: @unor Not really; as long as it can be reopened in something while preserving the user's rearranged state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind a little bit of simple coding then you could easily put something like this together with [Python 2](http://www.python.org) and [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/) make **sure** you also get and install the Docs & Demos Package - in fact the demo includes a good starter for you with a couple of bitmaps and a text object that can be dragged and dropped as shown below.
[image]

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Completely customisable

Comment: Thanks: If I had the time, I would totally write this myself (probably even as you suggest, in Python), but my client has given me one day's notice and I think I'd rather spend my Sunday re-evaluating my life choices :P In the end, I went with LibreOffice and dropdown cells, rather than any drag-and-drop. It's close enough.